# How do I prepare my files for deployment on BES?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

A client of ours would like to use our application but their IT policy forbids access to App World, as I'm sure many IT policies do.

What files do I have to provide them so that they can push our application to their employees?

Would it be okay to zip the files and have their IT dept download the zip from somewhere on our server? I can imagine this being easier for us whenever we make updates to the application: have all our BES users download it from one central location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Upon building your application use [jadtool](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#jadtool) to compose correct jad file and extract cod files when your project cod file contains sibling cod files inside. Extracting will be done automatically by jadtool when necessary. Make sure that jad file contains correct application title, it can be set via setting key-value params of jadtool task. Otherwise application jad file will contain something like: com_yourcompany_yourapp.cod instead of "Your application".
2. Use [Alx tool](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#alx) to generate alx file for the project. In alx task properties specify separate builds for separated device OS versions. Use [preprocessor](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#preproc) to have one source code and many builds for separate device OS versions.
3. Provide your customer with two zip files. One - contains processed by `jadtool` cod files along with jad-file. This zip file for OTA installation if your customer will want to do that. Another zip file - cod files (not processed by jadtool) along with alx file.

Comment: Thanks. If I provide my cod files to our client could they not potentially decompile them using a tool like coddec???

Comment: Coddec does not work properly always. In most cases it fails with a runtime exception, especially on cod files created with SDK 5.0 and newer (6.0, 7.0). And when it works it generates code that cannot be compiled into cod file again without signigicant changes. If it is very important for you, then consider additional obfuscation. Check this link: http://goo.gl/XomJ6  But I do not recommend this. Because it decreases the product reliability.

Comment: After installing an app from AppWorld, any user can then pull out the cod files from the device by using bbsak, so there is no loss of privacy/security/obfuscation by handing out the cod files, if the app is already in AppWorld.

Comment: It is easy to pull any cod file from BlackBerry device. And upload it to another device. Bind your application to the device pin-code. Every device has unique pin-code. Upon downloading this app from AppWorld generate license key for a particular device (for its pin-code). Even someone installs your app on another device he will need to buy license code for that new device.

Answer (score 1):

Copy **cod** file from **deliverables** folder of your project and paste it at any folder in your PC.

Now change extension of cod file to zip format and extract it there, Then you will get many files with .cod extension. Copy these all extracted file to some folder at your server. Then user can simply download via using that particular path of your server's folder.